# Some misunderstanding in LINQ to entity

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have this linq to entity row:

```
myentity.CityType.Add(context.Set<SiteCityType>().FindAsync(2));
```

Where the entity is **myentity** and **SiteCityType** are defined entities.
and **CityType** is navigation property defined in **myentity** entity:

```
    public virtual ICollection<SiteCityType> CityType { get; set; }
```

The linq row above works properly but I need that **FindAsync** method get List:

```
myentity.CityType.Add(context.Set<SiteCityType>().FindAsync('some list of ints'));
```

Any idea how can I implement it?

Comment: I recommend you to implement your custom method(Create Repository and add method you like).

Comment: You could use Where(siteCityType => list.Contains(siteCityType.Id)) instead of FindAsync

Comment: @stefchri. add extenntion gets only single item not collection so there is a problem to make your example work

Comment: Why should we implement something that already exists? (`Contains`).

Answer (score 2):

Try create extension method:

```
    public static IEnumerable<SiteCityType> FindById(this SiteCityTypeRepository repository, int[] ids)
    {
        var result = from pr in repository.All() 
                     where ids.Contains(pr.ID)
                     select pr;
        return result.ToList();
    }
```

I suggest "All()" method to return not in-memory objects, for instance, IQueryable.
So actual implementation depends on your architecture.